# How to loop over all functions of another class using a list of function type elements?

Tags: python

I am trying to get a list of all the functions in a class and then looping over them so they are all executed without having to type each one out. For example:

```
class Foo:
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')

    def bar(self):
        print('bar')
```

Then in another file

```
import Foo
import inspect

newfoo = Foo()
functions = [f for f in inspect.getmembers(Foo, predicate=inspect.isfunction)]
for f in functions:
    newfoo.f[1]()
```

I am hoping to get:

```
foo
bar
```

But this gives the error

```
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'f'
```

Any ideas on how to execute this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `getattr` to call class method by name.

code:

```
import inspect
class Foo:
    def foo(self):
        print('foo')

    def bar(self):
        print('bar')

newfoo = Foo()
functions = [f for f in inspect.getmembers(Foo, predicate=inspect.isfunction)]
for f in functions:
    getattr(newfoo, f[0])()
```

result:

```
bar
foo
```

Comment: Actually, there is no need to use `getattr` here. the `functions` list is consist of tuples like this: `('bar', <function Foo.bar at 0x000002B1D1EC3940>)` Which the first element is the function's name and the second one is **the function**. you can simply call the function by calling the second element in this tuple. like this: `f[1]()`

Comment: MAHBOD NOURI  Yes that would work if the class and the executed code were in the same file, but the class is in a different file and is imported, so in order to call a function from that class you'll have to do newfoo.foo(). For my application, getattr is required

Answer (score 1):

You could even use it without the `inspect` module:

```
class Foo:
    def foo():
        print('foo')

    def bar():
        print('bar')


object_methods = [method_name for method_name in dir(Foo)
                  if not method_name.startswith("__") and
                  callable(getattr(Foo, method_name))]


print(object_methods)
```

This yields

```
['bar', 'foo']
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is almost correct. just change `newfoo.f[1]()` to `f[1]()` and it will work properly.

```
for f in functions:
    f[1]()
```